# Probability of measuring Energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-states

[image]

I have done the first part of the question, but in (b) and  (c) are struggling me .

I second part : 
My tutor wrote :

$$ P(req.) = \frac{|\int  \phi_E^*(x)*\psi(x,t) dx |^2}{|\int\: \psi^*(x,t)*\psi(x,t) dx|^2 } $$

For Third part : 
 $  \frac{|{A_E}|^2}{\sum_E  |{A_E}|^2 } $ . 
 How we can write those above expressions .

I have doubt in the equation above .It seems incorrect .
I think for the second part , numerator must be $E$ instead of $\phi$ . 
Can anyone please explain.?

Comment: You should try evaluating the equation your tutor gave you.  If you don't know how to do that, then you need to go review some earlier concepts from your class.  Use the orthonormality property of the $\phi_E$ functions.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: @John Rennie , I am not asking to answer the question , I just asked the logic behind the equation. Bill N , I know ,How to evaluate but I asked for explaination behind that equation or how to reach that ewuation.

Comment: How can energy $E$ be related to a probability.? It would help if you would write the equation you think is right.

Comment: @JEB Can  you throw some lights on right equation and try to give explaination behind that ?

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier if you assume $\psi(x)$ is normalized, then the total probability of anything is one, so that:

$$ \big|\int\: \psi^*(x,t)\psi(x,t) dx\big |^2  = \sum_E  |{A_E}|^2 = 1 $$

The the probability of measuring one of the eigenenergies, $E$, is:

$$ P(req.) = \big|\int  \phi_E^*(x)\psi(x,t) dx \big|^2$$

So that's just a projection of $\psi$ on the basis state $\phi_E$.

As an example, imagine some system with 3 eigenstates of energy $E_x$, $E_y$, $E_z$. All we know about the actual eigenfunctions is that they are orthonormal, so we can call them $\hat x$, $\hat y$, $\hat z$. The most general (normalized) state would then be:

$$ \psi(x, t) = A_x e^{iE_xt}\hat x + A_y e^{iE_yt}\hat y + A_z e^{iE_zt}\hat z  $$

which is something on the unit sphere with complex phases factors that all oscillate at differ rates, but they're just phase factors, so you can think of it a vector in 3-space:

$$ \psi(x) = A_x \hat x + A_y\hat y + A_z \hat z  $$

and worry about time dependence later.

The question "what is the probability of measuring $E_x$" is

$$P(E_x) = |A_x|^2$$

because you're selecting the amplitude along that direction and squaring it.

For the 3rd question, you have to find an energy weighted average, so for instance, the $\hat x$ state in this example contributes $|A_x|^2 E_x$. (Now here you expect and $E$ to appear, because the final result needs to have dimensions of energy).

The point of the 3 dimensional example was to give something you can visualize (mathematically), IRL it's usually an infinite dimensional Hilbert space.